# Transform the values of the features of a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I want to impute following transformations in the values:

1. The 'Name' column to show only the titles (for ex:Miss,Mr).
2. The 'Cabin' column to contain only the 1st letter (for ex:'C' instead of the whole 'C54'.

Please help me with a general solution lastly for such similar problems. Thank you.(This was in a jupyter notebook and I didn't know to properly present the code)

```
categoric.head()
output:
    Name                                                Cabin   
0   Braund, Mr. Owen Harris                             A23 
1   Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...   C85 
2   Heikkinen, Miss. Laina                              C54
3   Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)        C123    
4   Allen, Mr. William Henry                            B231
```

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` has an entire set of methods related to [String Handling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#string-handling) for `Series`.

The cabins requires you to slice the first letter:

```
categoric.Cabin.str[0]

#0    A
#1    C
#2    C
#3    C
#4    B
```

To get the titles, you can use `.str.extract`, with a capturing group with all different values separated by the vertical bar. Since `.` has a special meaning in patterns, need to escape it by preceding it with `\`:

```
categoric.Name.str.extract('(Mr\.|Mrs\.|Miss\.)')

#       0
#0    Mr.
#1   Mrs.
#2  Miss.
#3   Mrs.
#4    Mr.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
categoric.Name= categoric.Name.apply(lambda x: x.split(', ')[1].split('.')[0])
categoric.Cabin = categoric.Cabin.slice(0,1)
```

Comment: 'Series' object has no attribute 'slice'. The error while transforming 'Cabin' feature.